# PCB layout - Create common ground connection for 5V signal and 12V power

Tags: pcb-design, ground

For my board, which drives dc motor, I want to create a common ground that connects 5v gnd and 12V gnd, as shown in figure 1. The problem I am encountering, as shown in figure 2 is that eagle cad combines the two nets from each ground. After searching for answers, one possible solution is to use a zero ohm resistor between the two nets, as shown in figure 3. Is this the ideal way, to create a common ground?

[image: Figure 1]

!![image: Figure 2]

!![image: Figure 3]

Comment: I have seen what you need called "splitter", with a schematic symbol that looks like this --->>>---. The footprint mostly is two SMD pads really close together (probably like 0603 resistors) so you can bridge the gap with solder. I think you can also get your problem solved with a star ground.

Comment: You can also consider zero ohm resistors as you say. And inductors as well, since they behave as cables at DC (maybe to avoid ground loops you can use a really low inductance one, namely just a cable).

Comment: Also (and I'm sorry for dividing this in three different comments, I'm coming up with the answers as I post), you should consider low resistance resistors instead of 0 ohm, since some have big tolerances that can make them have more resistance and (in high power circuits) waste more power. You should calculate the consequences and pick the most suited solution for your particular case

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my query. I think i will go with soldering smd pads, since the pcb is a prototype. About zero ohm, I had my doubts too considering 
these resistors have tolerances but then even wires and jumpers have some resistance.